# cómo compartir variables de javascript a php?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, comparaciones

Estoy haciendo un proyecto pero necesito que se comparta una variable de `js` a `php`, ya puedo compartirlas pero no se comparan con un `if`, aunque son las mismas.

```
?>
<script>
    var va = prompt('desea continuar, escriba ok para continuar'); 
</script>
<?php

$va = "<script>document.writeln(va)</script>";
echo $va;
if ($va =='ok') {
    echo('1');
}else {
    echo('2');
}
```

El resultado sale **ok 2** al escribir **ok**, pero lo que quiero es que salga el 1, ya intente con `trim` para limpiar los espacios, pero no sale.
Que tengo mal?

Comment: De esa forma no podras. debes entender que el php es lenguaje servidor y javascript es de lado del cliente. para que envies una variable desde javascript, debes usar ajax

Answer (score 0):

Podrías pasar un parámetro vía get y recargar la página:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['resultado']) and ($_GET['resultado'] == 'ok')) {
  // lo que quieras hacer
}
else {
?>

  <script>
    var va = prompt('desea continuar, escriba ok para continuar'); 
    var url = window.location.href;    
    if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
      url += '&resultado=' + va
    }
    else {
      url += '?resultado=' + va
    }
    window.location.href = url;
  </script>
```

No he podido validar el código pero debería funcionarte sin problemas.

Comment: La respuesta podría ser correcta, pero si no se sabe que quiere hacer el OP podría llevar a confusión

Answer (score 0):

No puedes pasar variables del código JavaScript de la página actual al código PHP de la página actual ... El código PHP se ejecuta en el lado del servidor y no sabe nada sobre lo que está sucediendo en el lado del cliente.

Debes pasar variables al código PHP desde el formulario HTML utilizando otro mecanismo, como enviar el formulario utilizando los métodos GET o POST.

Si lo que quieres es poder ejecutar cosas en PHP sin tener que recargar la página se puede hacer usando `$.ajax(` o `$.GET(`

Segun las necesidades que tengas puedo modificar la respuesta para ampliar información.